# Fancybox 2 images does not appear on gallery and twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox-2

Well I cannot get working the simple example of fancybox gallery example, on click it only goes to image page and the beforeLoad event activates, but not showing image in box.

I am using the jquery version 1.8.3 and twitter 2.3.1

The script itself is added in the end of page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // $('ul.thumbnails').find('a.fancybox').click(function(e) {
    //   e.preventDefault();
    // });

    $('ul.thumbnails').find('a.fancybox').fancybox({
      beforeLoad : function() {
        console.log('Loaded');
      }
    });
    console.log('fancybox start');

     //This example works!!!
    // $.fancybox( '<div><h1>Lorem Lipsum</h1><p>Lorem lipsum</p></div>', {
    //   title : 'Custom Title'
    // });
  });
</script>



[
<a href=​"/​realestate/​image/​7150209096969e5da60a8e7283afc453.png/​800" class=​"thumbnail fancybox">​
<img style=​"width:​ 360px;​ height:​ 270px;​" alt src=​"/​realestate/​image/​7150209096969e5da60a8e7283afc453.png/​360">​
</a>​
, 
<a href=​"/​realestate/​image/​8f31e46f9ab617d00541f1bc60e2e3b1.png/​60" class=​"thumbnail fancybox">​
<img style=​"width:​ 60px;​ height:​ 60px;​" alt src=​"/​realestate/​image/​8f31e46f9ab617d00541f1bc60e2e3b1.png/​60">​
</a>​
, 
<a href=​"/​realestate/​image/​0a98662cc5df0c8b1bc97a9a7e8b9707.png/​60" class=​"thumbnail fancybox">​
<img style=​"width:​ 60px;​ height:​ 60px;​" alt src=​"/​realestate/​image/​0a98662cc5df0c8b1bc97a9a7e8b9707.png/​60">​
</a>​
]
```

Comment: I've never seen image paths with directories at the end like that. Maybe that's throwing Fancybox off.

Comment: @isherwood yes I think the problem were with filenames and also by setting the option type: 'image'.

Comment: If you've solved the problem you should update your question or answer it yourself so no one else spends time on it for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem is that the FancyBox didn't like the url's ending like this /80 so tried to make different img route. Another problem is that the Fancybox suposes that without img extension url is html content, so i set the option type to only images.

{ type: 'image' }